# How to load state before render is called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know the problem is that the page is rendering before my state as loaded in. I am using `react-google-maps` and trying to create markers from my users location. The problem is that the state is an empty array until the state is loaded in from redux. How do I deal with this problem. I will post the code below.

The function that cares about this is `generateInitialMarkers()` and it is getting items passed into it by the `constructor()` method in `this.state` on the `markers`.

```
/* global google */
import { default as React, Component } from 'react';
import raf from 'raf';
import canUseDOM from 'can-use-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Circle, InfoWindow, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';
import withScriptjs from 'react-google-maps/lib/async/withScriptjs';

const googleMapURL =
  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyA7XEFRxE4Lm28tAh44M_568fCLOP_On3k';
const geolocation =
  canUseDOM && navigator.geolocation
    ? navigator.geolocation
    : {
      getCurrentPosition(success, failure) {
        failure("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
      },
    };
const GeolocationExampleGoogleMap = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props =>
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} center={props.center}>
      {props.center &&
        <InfoWindow position={props.center}>
          <div>User's Location</div>
        </InfoWindow>}
      {props.center &&
        <Circle
          center={props.center}
          radius={props.radius}
          options={{
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 1,
          }}
        />}
      >
      {props.markers.map((marker, index) => {
        const onClick = () => props.onMarkerClick(marker);
        const onCloseClick = () => props.onCloseClick(marker);

        return (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            position={marker.position}
            title={(index + 1).toString()}
            onClick={onClick}
          >
            {marker.showInfo &&
              <InfoWindow onCloseClick={onCloseClick}>
                <div>
                  <strong>
                    <h2>
                      {marker.content}
                    </h2>
                  </strong>
                  <br />
                  <h3>Where we can add offer details!</h3>
                </div>
              </InfoWindow>}
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </GoogleMap>,
  ),
);

function generateInitialMarkers(items) {
  console.log('item', items);
  const markers = [];
  items.map((item, i) => {
    const newGeoArr = item.geolocation.split(',');
    item.position = { lat: newGeoArr[0], lng: newGeoArr[1] };
    markers.push({
      position: item.position,
      content: item.description,
      showInfo: false,
    });
  });

  console.log('markers: ', markers);
  return markers;
}

class OfferMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      center: null,
      content: null,
      radius: 100000,
      markers: generateInitialMarkers(this.props.browser.items),
    };

    const isUnmounted = false;

    this.handleMarkerClick = this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseClick = this.handleCloseClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
      markers: this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
        if (marker === targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: true,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
    });
  }

  handleCloseClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
      markers: this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
        if (marker === targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: false,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const tick = () => {
      if (this.isUnmounted) {
        return;
      }
      this.setState({ radius: Math.max(this.state.radius - 200, 0) });

      if (this.state.radius > 100) {
        raf(tick);
      }
    };

    geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        if (this.isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }
        this.setState({
          center: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          },
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.',
        });

        raf(tick);
      },
      (reason) => {
        if (this.isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }

        this.setState({
          center: {
            lat: 60,
            lng: 105,
          },
          content: `Error: The Geolocation service failed (${reason}).`,
        });
      },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isUnmounted = true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GeolocationExampleGoogleMap
        googleMapURL={googleMapURL}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }}>loading...</div>}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
        center={this.state.center}
        content={this.state.content}
        radius={this.state.radius}
        onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
        onCloseClick={this.handleCloseClick}
        markers={this.state.markers}
      />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ browser }) {
  return { browser };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OfferMap);
```

Comment: have you tried the `componentWillMount` lifecycle method?

Comment: Yes I have tried this

Comment: Have you tried using setTimeout to 1 second (this is a javascript function) in your componentDidMount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to not call generateInitialMarkers() in your state, if the expected props don't exist, yet...

```
markers: (props.browser.items.length > 0) ?
 generateInitialMarkers(props.browser.items) : ""
```

Then once the component receives the desired browser.items props, add them to state

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ markers: generateInitialMarkers(nextProps.browser.items) })
}
```

You may also need to prevent your render() function / GeolocationExampleGoogleMap component from calling this.state.markers until a proper value is assigned.

Keeping in mind that this is a bit hacky.

A more desired solution would be to ensure that you are passing the desired props before calling the OfferMap component.

---

Further Reading

Take a look at this page to gain a good understanding of react component lifecycle:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Also, it sounds like you're going to want to map your redux state to properties within your component. Have a look at this page as well:

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: Are you saying to do `this.setState({markers: generateMarkers(this.props.browser.items})` inside of componentDidMount(), not sure exactly what you are saying. Just saying look at this doesn't really give me an answer.

Comment: Modified my original answer. Let me know if that helps.